# K-means tree VS randomized KD-tree?

Tags: tree, k-means, kdtree

I was reading [these](http://image.ntua.gr/iva/files/ann.pdf) slides. In particular, at slide 52 it's stated:

> In our experiments, we have found that either of two algorithms can
>   have the best performance, depending on the dataset and desired
>   precision

However, in the previous slide only in case (a) K-means tree has a better performance than randomized kd-tree, while in the other three experiments kd-tree is definitely a winner.

Is that correct or am I reading something wrong here? If so, why they say that the best algorithm is data-set-dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing the graphs in the slide that you pointed you can observe that:

- In (a) **for 100k** SIFT matches **K-means performs a bit better** when balancing speed/precision;
- In (b) when scaling up from 100K SIFT to 31M, RKD-Trees are able to perform faster, **however speed slightly degrades if you want the best precision** in finding those matches;
- And in (c) searching with **RKD-Tree perform better on datasets which do not have true matches in respect to the query**.

So they really are dataset dependant. For instance, you can conclude that RKD-Tree perform faster for larger datasets, however if precision is a relevant metric for whatever task you are trying to achieve, RKD-Trees performance will be similar to a K-means search.